# Выравнивание чисел Java

Tags: java

Приветствую товарищи! подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно сделать форматирование чисел? в первом столбце, числа должны быть выровнены по правой границе, во втором столбце по точке

пример:

```
a =    4        x = 343.34
b =  332        y =   1.2332
с =   48        z =  23.2
```

значения переменных будет вводить пользователь, а мне лишь нужно выводить их как в примере. Пытался выводить разными форматами по справочнику, но ничего не получается

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В первом случае нужно делать одинаковую длину строк с числами путем добавления пробелов перед числом 
Например: узнаете длину `ln` самого большого числа,  и перед остальными числами добавляете n пробелов, где `n` = разница по модулю между `ln` и длинной исходного числа 
Во втором случае я думаю можно так же. Только округлять числа до целых, и добавлять n пробелов по той же формуле

Видно что в числах с 3мя знаками 0 пробелов, в числах с 2мя 1 пробел, а в числах с 1м знаком, 2 пробела 
3 знака (большее число) - 1 знак(исходное) = 2 пробела 
3 - 1 = 2 
3 - 2 = 1 
Перед ними количество пробелов, равно разнице кол-ва цифр в макс.числе и кол-ва цифр исходного числа

Comment: благодарю за подсказку)